# Tooltip on advanced datagrid column in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have a advanced data grid with columns as status, enabled, owner, name.

I will get data for status as 'applicable' or 'success' or 'failure' .
When the status is coming as 'applicable',  i have to show the tool tip when move the mouse over there. Can you please help me out how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a GridItemRenderer and here is some sample code to put within the script block of your custom GridItemRenderer:

```
import mx.controls.ToolTip;
import mx.core.IUIComponent;
import mx.managers.ToolTipManager;

public var applicableToolTip:ToolTip;

private function createToolTip(event:Event):void {
    if (data["status"] == "applicable") {
        var stagePoint:Point = event.target.localToGlobal(new Point(event.target.x, event.target.y));
        applicableToolTip = ToolTipManager.createToolTip(
            "Your applicable message here",
            stagePoint.x,
            stagePoint.y,
            null,
            IUIComponent(event.currentTarget)
        ) as ToolTip;
    }
}

private function destroyToolTip(event : Event) : void {
    if (applicableToolTip != null)
        ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(applicableToolTip);
}
```

Then in the label field within the renderer add the attributes `rollOver="createToolTip(event)"` and `rollOut="destroyToolTip(event)"`

Comment: !Mat:- applicableToolTip is throwing null object reference error when the status is not 'applicable'.

Comment: That makes sense because the tool tip never gets created for the other status types. Just need to check for it in the destroy tool tip. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

If a `TooTip Manager` is not needed then you can have a `dataTip` function  which constructs the message and set `displayToolTip` property of column to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If your tooltip is inside your xml data you can specify `dataTipField` on `DataGridColumn`.

For example:

```
var col:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
col.dataTipField = "@statusTooltip";
col.showDataTips = true;
```

if your xml item looks something like:

```
<item id="..." status="applicable" statusTooltip="My tootlip text"/>
```